# $\varphi: M \to N$ is onto if and only if for all $R$-mod homomorphisms $\alpha : F \to N$ there exists an $R$-mod homomorphism $\beta : F \to M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring, $F$ a nonzero free $R$-module, and let $\varphi : M \to N$ be a homomorphism of $R$-modules. Prove that $\varphi$ is onto if and only if for all $R$-module homomorphisms $\alpha : F \to N$ there exists an $R$-module homomorphism $\beta : F \to M$ such that $\alpha=\varphi \circ \beta$.

To show $\varphi$ is surjective, we let $F=R^{\oplus N}$ and consider the canonical projection $\pi: R^{\oplus N} \to N$. For $\pi$ there exists $\beta: R^{\oplus N} \to M$ such that $\pi = \varphi \circ \beta$. Since the natural inclusion $i: N \to R^{\oplus N}$ is an $R$-module hom, then $\mathrm{Id}_N = \pi \circ i= \varphi \circ \beta \circ i$. Thus, $\varphi$ has a right inverse and so it is surjective.

**I am stuck as far as the other direction. Any help?**

Comment: The way I'm reading the exercise, $F$ is fixed. You don't get to choose which free $R$-module it is.

Comment: From a categorical point of view, using the fact that the free $R$-module functor is left adjoint to the underlying set functor, call it $U$, quickly turns this into an easy problem of set theory. That is, we have if $F$ is freely generated by the (assumed non-empty) set $S$, then $R\mathsf{Mod}(F,N)\cong\mathbf{Set}(S,UN)$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I guess I misread the question. So, my solution is wrong. Any hints for either direction?

Comment: Free modules are projective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments $F$ is fixed, you cannot just choose it as you want.

Assume that $A\subseteq F$ is a (nonempty) free basis.

"$\Leftarrow$" Assume that $\varphi$ is not onto. Let $x\in N$ be such that $x\not\in im(\varphi)$. Note that this also means that $x\not\in im(\varphi\circ\beta)$ for any $\beta$. Now take $\alpha:F\to N$ by definining $\alpha(a)=x$ for some (all) $a\in A$. Since $A$ is a basis then $\alpha$ is a well defined and unique homomorphism. But then $x\in im(\alpha)$ even though $x\not\in im(\varphi\circ\beta)$ and so there's no chance for $\alpha=\varphi\circ\beta$ to hold, regardless of what $\beta$ is.

This contradiction means that $\varphi$ has to be onto. $\Box$

"$\Rightarrow$" So $\varphi:M\to N$ is a given onto homomorphism and $\alpha:F\to N$ is an arbitrary homomorphism. Since $\varphi$ is onto then for any $a\in A$ there is $m_a\in M$ such that $\varphi(m_a)=\alpha(a)$. Now let $\beta:F\to M$ be given by $\beta(a)=m_a$ for $a\in A$. Since $A$ is a free basis then $\beta$ is well defined and unique.

Now for any $a\in A$ we have:

$$(\varphi\circ\beta)(a)=\varphi(\beta(a))=\varphi(m_a)=\alpha(a)$$

and so $\varphi\circ\beta$ and $\alpha$ are equal on $A$. Since $A$ is a basis then  they are equal on whole $F$. $\Box$

Comment: Very nice. The $(\Leftarrow)$ direction can be done just by contrapositive.

Comment: There's no need for an indirect proof here. Your first subproof is simplified just by saying for every $x\in N$, define $\alpha(a)=x$. Then $x\in\operatorname{im}(\varphi)$ because $x=\alpha(a)=\varphi(\beta(a))$ for any $a\in A$.

Comment: For $\Leftarrow$: Let $n \in N$ and let $\alpha_n(a)=n$ for all $a \in A$. Then $\alpha$ is well-defined. By assumption, for this $\alpha_n$ there exists $\beta_n$ such that $\alpha_n=\varphi \beta_n$. So, $n=\varphi(\beta_n(s))$ and so $Im (\varphi) = N$. So, $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: Why is $F$ fixed? The only distinguishing property it seems to have is that it is some non-zero free module...